# Not able to store large string in db in RoR 3

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, string-length

I'm only allow to store around 250 characters in db column. When I try to add large string it automatically omit the extra character. The type I used in scaffold is `string`. How can I store large strings in db. I'm using `MySQL` as db.

Comment: if you are only allowed 250 characters then you are out of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `:string` as your column type, use `:text` - it will give you *much* more space to store your string.

Answer (score 3):

use data type "text" instead of "string"

**CHAR( )   :**        A fixed section from 0 to 255 characters long.

**VARCHAR( ):** A variable section from 0 to 255 characters long.

**TINYTEXT:**   A string with a maximum length of 255 characters.

**TEXT:**           A string with a maximum length of 65535 characters.

**BLOB:**           A string with a maximum length of 65535 characters.

**MEDIUMTEXT:** A string with a maximum length of 16777215 characters.

**MEDIUMBLOB:** A string with a maximum length of 16777215 characters.

**LONGTEXT:**   A string with a maximum length of 4294967295 characters.

**LONGBLOB:**   A string with a maximum length of 4294967295 characters.

Comment: As you are late in suggesting and I have accepted @dan's answer. I can not accept your answer. But +1 for the information. :-)